# Match first and last name to 2nd column then output corresponding 3rd value

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm trying to create an import csv.  the sheet has the following data

ImportID, 1stname, lastname, FirstName, LastName, inport_ID
1, bob, Abraham, bob, Abbott,
2, sue, Abraham, bob,   Abraham, 1
3,  Jill,   Abraham,    jill,   Abraham, 3
4,  Michael,    Adkinson,   jill,   Abraham, 3

I'm trying to match the 4th & 5th column to the 2nd & 3rd column and then output the 1st column in a 6th column.  I'm thinking that I have to use a combo of vlookup and ISNUMBER but I can't find a clear description of their functions enough to combine them w/ out losing my hair.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: What software do you want to do this in?

Comment: Excel 2011 for Mac; does it matter from one version of excel to another?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are lots of resources out there if you search double lookup.

One way to do it is to use an index and match.

```
=INDEX($A$2:$A$5,MATCH(D2,IF($C$2:$C$5=E2,$B$2:$B$5),0))
```

This formula is an array formula so needs to be entered with **ctrl+shift+enter** or the mac equivalent (see image below).

How it works.

Index takes an array (A2:A5) and a row number in that array (with other inputs being optional.

Match matches D2 to the array B2:B5 and returns the position where it matches

The if statement basically blanks out all the rows where E2 does not match column C.

[image]

Comment: Doesn't quite do what I was hoping, maybe I described it wrong.  I need to match 1st and last name in D2:E5 to the 1st and last in B2:C5.  D2:E5 will have repeats, B2:C5 will all be uniques.

Comment: For me it returns exactly what you have in your table above except there is a n/a error in the first row due to no match.  Could you tell me what it is doing that is wrong.  This formula finds the matches in columns B and C for the current row in D and E.  This formula would go in cell F2 and be copied down.  Don't forget teh ctrl+shift+enter

Comment: ctrl+shift+enter isn't a thing on Mac office 2011 as far as I could tell.  The fault wasn't yours, I just didn't describe it completely accurately.

Comment: I didn't realize you were using a mac, I've added an image of the buttons to press to enter the formula and it should work.